# Cleanest way to put condition inside CodeIgniter ActiveRecord

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, activerecord

I need to put condition inside CodeIgniter ActiveRecord, here's my code:

```
public function getData($numb, $period, $status){
    $this->db->select("COUNT(*) AS jml")
             ->from()
             ->where_not_in();
             if($status !== 'all'){
                $this->db->where("LAYANAN.TGL_LAYANAN BETWEEN DATEADD(" . $period ."," . $numb .", GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()");
             }
             $this->db->where_in()
             ->group_by("");
    return $query = $this->db->get();
}
```

I also need to put `$period` and `$numb` variables inside `where` statement. It works, but I don't really like how my code looks like. It looks so dirty. Can you guys give me solution in order to achieve cleaner code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getData($numb, $period, $status){
$this->db->select("COUNT(*) AS jml")
         ->from()
         ->where_not_in()
         ->where_in()
         ->group_by("");
if($status !== 'all'){
    $this->db->where("LAYANAN.TGL_LAYANAN BETWEEN DATEADD(" . $period ."," . $numb .", GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()");
}
return $query = $this->db->get();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Utilize double-quote for the overall string and single quotes around the arguments to `DATEADD`

```
$this->db->where("LAYANAN.TGL_LAYANAN 
                  BETWEEN DATEADD(`$period`,`$numb`, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()");
```